# How do I create a LaTeX package?

Tags: package-writing

I would like to jump into the cold waters of LaTeX package creation, mostly for procrastination reasons...but I haven't a clue how to start. For example, a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/onlyitems-how-to-select-specific-items-from-an-item-list) of mine got some nice answers. I would like to take one of these answers and create a package from it.

- How do I start?
- If others find it useful, how should I document it?
- How do I publish it?

Perhaps I should say, I do not want anyone to do the work for me...I would much prefer an explanation on how I could do it myself!

Comment: Well creating a simple package isn't difficult. Actually putting everything in a `.sty` file is already enough. See [Make your own .sty files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/make-your-own-sty-files) for the minimal set of headers (which are also technically optional, but should be added to any real package).

Comment: To get an overview about packages to create a key-value-syntax see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package

Comment: Then have a look at [clsguide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/clsguide) and [dtxtut](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dtxtut). They show the classic way to write package files. You should upload your new package to CTAN when it is finished, see [What is good practice when preparing a package for CTAN](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/what-is-good-practice-when-preparing-a-package-for-ctan).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

These are three related but different questions. We have already got some good answers on this site. So perhaps let's take this place to summarize it.

This answer is community wiki, so feel free to edit it. Of course you can add more information than site links.

### Starting package writing

- [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming)
- [Classes and packages – what's the difference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21909/classes-and-packages-whats-the-difference)
- [Make your own .sty files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/make-your-own-sty-files)
- [Style/class tutorials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials)
- [Reference guide to begin writing a class and/or a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/reference-guide-to-begin-writing-a-class-and-or-a-package)

### Documenting packages

- [How do I document my style files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13028/how-do-i-document-my-style-files)
- [Packages for documenting self written packages (sty-files)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30730/packages-for-documenting-self-written-packages-sty-files)
- [What is the gold standard of package documentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31785/what-is-the-gold-standard-of-package-documentation)
- [How to document a expl3 macro using dtx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115814/how-to-document-a-expl3-macro-using-dtx)
- [`dtxtut.pdf` "How to Package Your LaTeX Package"](https://ctan.org/pkg/dtxtut)
- [Joseph Wright's blog post "A model .dtx file"](https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/)

### Publishing packages

- [How does one publish/promote a new package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10591/how-does-one-publish-promote-a-new-package)
- [How can I contribute to CTAN?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/854/how-can-i-contribute-to-ctan)
- [What is good practice when preparing a package for CTAN?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/what-is-good-practice-when-preparing-a-package-for-ctan)
- [How to upload my packages or document classes to CTAN?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23892/how-to-upload-my-packages-or-document-classes-to-ctan)
- [CLI tool to upload to CTAN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27244/cli-tool-to-upload-to-ctan)

Answer (score 25):

I've spent around a day trying to build my own package. Not impressed by the vast amount of [sorry, but your princess is in another castle](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/but-our-princess-is-in-another-castle); I've decided to write up my findings. This is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) "[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)" project, and has taken some shortcuts to keep code size and answer size down.

The answer will help you understand what plugs together and how.
It will also show you how to run your package locally, so you can sanity check your TeX installation and your package.

## Starting point

I'll start this by showing what my TeX would look like without using a package.
The aim of the package is to move the definition of `\hello` into a package called `mypackage`.

`document.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\hello}{Hello, World!}

\begin{document}
    \hello
\end{document}
```

I managed to achieve this goal, and by the end of this answer you too can use the following TeX.

`package.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}

\begin{document}
    \hello
\end{document}
```

## Making a package

### The package file

There are [two types of packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21910); styles (`.sty`) and classes (`.cls`). For this we'll be making a style. When writing your own style or class I'd recommend looking at Wikibooks' [Creating Packages](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Packages) page.

Versions in LaTeX are generally provided as dates in the ISO 8601 date format, YYYY/MM/DD.
And so when you specify both the TeX and your package version you should enter both in that form.

`mypackage.sty`

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2020/02/28 1.0.0 Tutorial project]

\newcommand{\hello}{Hello, World!}

\endinput
```

The above is the style file I made.

- `\NeedsTeXFormat` specifies which version of TeX is required, with the version (date) also specified.
- `\ProvidesPackage` specifies what package we are defining. I have:

  - Called the package `mypackage`,
  - Set the TeX version to todays date,

    > 2020/02/28
  - Specified the version in [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/)

    > 1.0.0
  - Added a short description of the project.

    > Tutorial project
- `\newcommand` defines the wanted `\hello` command.
- `\endinput` signals the end of the style file.

### Install it locally

It's best if you sanity check the code.
And so we can install the package locally.
This is required to know, if you need to install your own or another persons package.

1. [Find where your TEXMF folder is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138).
2. Make the folders required by the [TeX Directory Structure](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-tds.html), TDS, standard.

   Since we're making a LaTeX project, we'll place it in `texmf/tex/latex`.
   And to keep the folder clean, we'll place our package in the `mypackage` folder.
3. Copy your package to the newly created folder.

In the shell it would look something like this.
**Note**: Ensure you change `%USERPROFILE%/texmf` to whatever your output is.

```
$ kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
%USERPROFILE%/texmf
$ mkdir %USERPROFILE%/texmf/tex/latex/mypackage/
$ cp mypackage.sty %USERPROFILE%/texmf/tex/latex/mypackage/
```

If your package isn't found, because your TeX isn't TDS compliant, then you can tell TeX where it is.

```
$ texhash %USERPROFILE%/texmf
```

### Testing the package

We can now run `package.tex` and it outputs "Hello, World!" as expected.

## Documenting it

### Converting from sty to dtx

The standard for documenting TeX projects is through [dtx](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-dtx).
This is some black magic that houses both the documentation and the package at the same time.
To achieve this feat, the code contains a vast amount of comments and requires an installer.

The ins file extracts the information from the dtx and builds the sty or cls file.
The code is mostly boilerplate.

`mypackage.ins`

```latex
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\usedir{tex/latex/mypackage}
\generate{\file{mypackage.sty}{\from{mypackage.dtx}{package}}}
\Msg{Please move mypackage.sty to a TDS directory}
\endbatchfile
```

- You should change all occurrences of `mypackage` to the name of your package.
- You can change `\Msg` to whatever you want.
  You can also include additional messages if you want the message split over multiple lines.

  Think `print`, `echo` or `sys.stdout.write`.

### Making the dtx

To build the documentation, you run TeX on the dtx file. Just like you do with any other TeX document.

`mypackage.dtx`

```latex
% \iffalse
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2020/02/28 1.0.0 Tutorial project]
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
    \DocInput{mypackage.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \begin{macro}{\hello}
% This is the function to display "Hello world!"
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\hello}{Hello world!}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
\endinput
```

When the file is run through TeX, it evaluates the section from `\documentclass` through `\end{document}`, much like any other TeX file. If you comment out the `\DocInput` line then you just get an empty file.

The magic happens when `\DocInput` runs. This evaluates the file a second time, this time removing the comments from the file. The `\iffalse` and `\fi` cause the entire first section to not be run on the second evaluation, preventing `\DocInput` from running a second time, and preventing `\NeedsTeXFormat` from running ever.

From here, the rest of the file is simple.

- `%<package>` is a special comment which includes the line, uncommented, in sty.
  This is as we specified it, `package`, in the ins.

  ```latex
  \generate{\file{mypackage.sty}{\from{mypackage.dtx}{package}}}
  ```

  **Note**: Do not put a space between `%` and `<` otherwise it won't be included.
- `\begin{macro}` documents the macro with the following line as the description.
- `\newcommand{\hello}{...}` is exported to the sty.
- `\endinput` is exported to the sty.

### Install it locally

To install the package we need to run the ins to extract the sty from the dtx.

After extracting the sty, we then just install it as we did before.
In the shell this would look something like this.

```
$ tex mypackage.ins
$ cp mypackage.sty %USERPROFILE%/texmf/tex/latex/mypackage/
```

You can also see the documentation by running the dtx.

```
$ pdflatex mypackage.dtx
$ ./mypackage.pdf
```

## Publishing

Now that you know what sty, cls, ins and dtx files are, and how to install them, understanding how to publish your TeX package is really simple. And the links provided by Stefan Kottwitz's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34176) can better describe this.

## Going forward

I'd like to restate that this is an MVCE of how to make and install your own documented package.
And so I've cut corners and not covered half the tooling available.

- Wikibooks has a more complete description on [how to build a sty or cls](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Packages).
- Scott Pakin's [How to Package Your LaTeX Package](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/dtxtut/dtxtut.pdf) on how to write your own dtx and ins.
- The links in Stefan Kottwitz's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34176), as now you should have enough understanding of the entire system to understand the posts individually.

Comment: I must say this answer was extremely helpful. I've learned about `.cls` and `.sty` files and training for a while, but never tried the "next step" into `.dtx` and `.ins`. Now I found a simple guide to follow this "not so simple" steps. Thanks (+1).

Comment: The converting process from sty and cis to dix seems very manual. If I have my package split into several files to keep things organized when developing, copying the contents of each one Into a dtx each time I do a release sounds horrible. I wouldn't want to develop within the dtx because that isn't runnable. Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Logan but that is backwards, the intention is to generate `.sty` from `.dtx` not the other way round. If you have written `.sty` directly you do not need  a `.dtx`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so the standard would be to only maintain `.dtx` files and each time you test during development you'd generate sty files by running `latex mypackage.ins`?

Comment: or a build system such as l3build (or make or a custom shell script or ...) which does that for you @Logan