# How to document a expl3 macro using dtx

Tags: documentation, expl3, dtx

I am writing the documentation to a package implemented in `expl3` using `ltxdoc`, and the relevant part would look like

```
% \begin{macro}{\conteq_args_once}
% Some explanation
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\cs_new:Npn \conteq_args_once:Nn #1#2 {
   \exp_not:o {#1 {#2}}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \conteq_args_once:Nn {NV}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
```

Unfortunately, this give me

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.385 % \begin{macro}{\conteq_args_once}
```

but `\conteq\_args\_once:Nnn` does not work either. How do I correctly annotate the documentation for such a function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While you can start form `ltxdoc` and 'roll your own', the recommended approach is to use `l3doc`, which is the class used the the LaTeX team for `expl3` itself. This is currently a rather large collection of hacks, but does deal correctly with things like `_` in names, and also provides a richer set of documentation environments than `ltxdoc`. Regrettably, `l3doc` is lacking really comprehensive documentation: as I say, it's not exactly perfect internally! You can typeset `l3doc.dtx` to at least get some information, however.

Perhaps the best way to get the hang of things is to take a look at some of the LaTeX3 sources. I'd recommend avoiding `l3doc.dtx` itself and probably `l3bootstrap.dtx`, `l3names,dtx` and `l3basics.dtx` as they are atypical: something like `l3clist.dtx` is probably a rather better place to look. (As well as the use of `l3doc`, the sources show the 'house style' the team have standardised on. We are keen to encourage that as a more general '`expl3` code style': while you might not totally agree with every decision, in the long term it would be good if most `expl3` code looks the same irrespective of author, as this will aid with maintenance.)

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Please register your prefix(es) :-)

Comment: You might also take a look at my [`xpeek`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpeek); it attempts to use `l3doc`, but it’s a *much* smaller package than the LaTeX3 team’s stuff.

Comment: Note particularly the use of [`l3docstrip`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3docstrip), which helps keep your internal functions within your reserved namespace by translating `@@` within macro code to your chosen prefix.

Answer (score 3):

What I do is use [`skdoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/skdoc) (which I've written, although since it's based on [`ydoc`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ydoc) presumably this'll work with at least `ydoc` as well assuming you load `expl3`), and issue the following before the implementation part of the documentation:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn\ExplHack{
    \char_set_catcode_letter:n{ 58 }
    \char_set_catcode_letter:n{ 95 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\ExplHack
```

This makes the `macro` environments (as well as `\cs` and friends) read underscores and colons  as “letters” (i.e. part of the macro name) as appropriate in LaTeX3 code.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled over the same problem and came across this post. Although it's probably best to adopt `l3doc` or another more advanced class, for now I needed a quick fix since I did not have time to dive into another documentation class. For those that are in the same situation: You can add

```
\def\MakePrivateLetters{
    \catcode`\@=11\relax
    \catcode`\_=11\relax
    \catcode`\:=11\relax
}
```

into the preamble of the driver code in the dtx file and then `expl3` names should not be a problem anymore.