# How do I register the prefix of my expl3 package?

Tags: latex3, expl3

This question needs an easy to find answer here, so:

[I was told](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115814/how-to-document-a-expl3-macro-using-dtx#comment256471_115816) that I can and should register prefixes of my macro names in my `expl3` using packages. How do I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, a bit of background. Registration is of course not 'compulsory' but is encouraged: the idea is to have a much better idea of who looks after which code than is the case with LaTeX2e modules. The prefix register is available [from GitHub](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/l3kernel/doc/l3prefixes.csv). There is also a typeset version of the key information : http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3prefixes.pdf.

Registration simply requires informing the team that a prefix should be added to the database. The preferred method is to send an e-mail to `modules@latex-project.org` with as a minimum details of the prefix, the module name it goes with and the person registering. We also record things like home pages, code repositories and issue tracker locations if they are given. In practice I look after the list, e-mailing me directly will also work, or you can send something to LaTeX-L yourself: I follow that list so will pick it up.

Once registers, I send a message to the LaTeX-L list (see http://latex-project.org/code.html) so the information is public. It's therefore important to note that the e-mail address you give will be publicly-available.

Comment: What about pull requests via GitHub, are these also welcome?

Comment: I salute the idea of keeping a database of prefixes. However, is there not a risk of ill-intentioned people registering loads of prefixes simply to prevent other people from using them? A parallel would be domain names on the Internet...

Comment: @Jubobs In principal yes, but the plan is that other than a few 'team reserved' names I'm not adding anything to the list that isn't on CTAN and so effectively 'taken' in any case.