# Using minted in l3doc documentation

Tags: minted, fancyvrb, l3doc

When using `minted` in a `.dtx` file with `l3doc` in any way one will lose syntax highlighting as shown below (where the first and fourth segment are minted outputs and the second and third verbatim):

[image: missing highlighting]

You see that either some tokens are gobbled from the beginning (verbatim and minted) or all code is shown, but not highlighted (verbatim and minted).

*Question:* How to fix that behavior?

MWE:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% License here
%<*driver>
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
\input l3docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
\endpreamble
\postamble
\endpostamble
\generate{\file{test.sty}{\from{test.dtx}{pkg,cfg}}}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</driver>
%
%<*driver|class>
\RequirePackage{expl3}
%</driver|class>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%\iffalse
%<*driver>
%\fi
\begin{minted}{latex}
\begin{testme}
\item{example} Mustermann
\end{testme}
\end{minted}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{testme}
\item{example} Mustermann
\end{testme}
\end{verbatim}
%\iffalse
%</driver>
%\fi
% \begin{verbatim}
% \begin{testme}
% \item{example} Mustermann
% \end{testme}
% \end{verbatim}
% \begin{minted}{latex}
% \begin{testme}
% \item{example} Mustermann
% \end{testme}
% \end{minted}
% \endinput
```

<sub>This is not about using minted for the macrocode (see [l3doc in combination with minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120692/l3doc-in-combination-with-minted))</sub>

Comment: This is self-answered to share my experience working around a not working minted. If anyone has a better suggestion please answer too.

Answer (score 3):

The `l3doc` class uses `fancyvrb` to enhance the verbatim environment. To make all verbatim environments fancy it does

```
\fvset{gobble=2}
\cs_gset_eq:NN \verbatim \Verbatim
\cs_gset_eq:NN \endverbatim \endVerbatim
```

The problem with that is the interference with packages like `minted` which also rely on `fancyvrb`. Knowing what `l3doc` does it is easy to patch for case 1 as one just has to set `\fvset{gobble=0}` in the preamble. However that would result in examples 3 and 4 printing percent characters. So when using a `fancyvrb` environment within the `%` logic one has to explicitly set `\fvset{gobble=2}`. That will result in the following:

[image: minted output]

As you can see the code is printed in all cases, but minted syntax highlighting will only work when leaving the percent prefixed context.

Code:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% License here
%<*driver>
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
\input l3docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
\endpreamble
\postamble
\endpostamble
\generate{\file{test.sty}{\from{test.dtx}{pkg,cfg}}}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</driver>
%
%<*driver|class>
\RequirePackage{expl3}
%</driver|class>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{minted}
\fvset{gobble=0}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%\iffalse
%<*driver>
%\fi
\begin{minted}{latex}
\begin{testme}
\item{example} Mustermann
\end{testme}
\end{minted}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{testme}
\item{example} Mustermann
\end{testme}
\end{verbatim}
%\iffalse
%</driver>
%\fi
% \fvset{gobble=2}
% \begin{verbatim}
% \begin{testme}
% \item{example} Mustermann
% \end{testme}
% \end{verbatim}
% \fvset{gobble=2}
% \begin{minted}{latex}
% \begin{testme}
% \item{example} Mustermann
% \end{testme}
% \end{minted}
% \endinput
```