# Glossary-esque list of macros in package documentation

Tags: glossaries, documentation, definition

I've been on an hours-long journey looking for what should be common TeX knowledge, but without avail. I might just not know the correct search terms to do an efficient search, so I think it's worth asking about.

I want to document a handful of the macros I've written in LaTeX (for instance, `\foo{}` and `bar{}{}`). I've read several CTAN documentation PDFs in the past, and there seems to be one prevalent way of formatting the macros a package has to offer: the macro name (in \texttt style) shifted into the left margin, and an explanatory paragraph to the right. I've put an example from the `xcolor` package's docs below.

[image: xcolor documentation]

Additionally, packages like `mdframed` have a slightly altered (e.g. coloured) way of formatting such a glossary-like list (also notice the default values right-aligned on the macro name's line):

[image: mdframed documentation]

The style I am wanting to use is the one used by `macros2e`, as seen below: I like the colours, the stylised arguments and the frames. Now, the source for `macros2e` is found [here](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/macros2e/src/default/); however, from what I can deduce, the styles I am wanting to use are invoked via `\Macro` or `\DescribeMacro`, but as a beginner, I can't make head nor tail of how they are defined.

[image: macros2e documentation]

The three examples above are all glossary-like (I have my doubts as to whether they're generated using glossaries), so I'm assuming they're all style variants of a single standard environment or other structure. **What is that standard?**

From what I gather from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34175/how-do-i-create-a-latex-package) community wiki post's top answer, I might be looking at something called a "style" file, but that's a whole 'nother can of worms -- not particularly beginner-friendly. I'd say there is currently a lack of centralised, minimal, straight-forward examples (in simple LaTeX-done-properly) of how to write such documentations.

Comment: `macros2e` uses `ydoc-desc`, you can find the manual here: https://ctan.org/pkg/ydoc

Answer (score 1):

The manual of `macros2e`uses `ydoc-desc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ydoc-desc}

\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro\foo{<macro arguments>}
\lipsum[1]

\DescribeMacro\bar{<macro arguments>}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find the documentation here: https://ctan.org/pkg/ydoc

Comment: Do `xcolor` and `mdframed` also use `ydoc` (alluding to the standard I mention in my post)?

Comment: The standard package is `ltxdoc`, but `mdframed` has it's own `ltxmdf.cls`. There are a lot of different packages to do the job: https://ctan.org/topic/doc-supp