# Information for maintainers of packages

Tags: packages

I have an interest in making my own latex packages for distribution.  As I am still a novice is this, does there exist any official latex information on how to write and maintain packages?

My main focus is how to avoid package clashes, disabling certain functionalities should a user want to use a different packages from the ones defined in my style files, etc.

Comment: Seriously? You asked this same question with a different title 2 days ago. And as I pointed out then, you could test this yourself in about 20 seconds.

Comment: There could be some misunderstandings,  What I am introspecting has more to do with finding out the general rules for writing style files.  Is there any formal guide intended for people wanting to write packages?  In the case of Gnu there is the `Information for maintainers of GNU software`.  Is there something equivalent for maintainers of latex packages.  I did not mean to frustrate you, but to learn from other who know better.

Comment: As- I write a package, I could define `\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}`.  But suppose a person using the package does not want such a setting when using my style file.  What can I do that will give him the possibility of not using the setting, but let him using the normal non-bold typeface?

Comment: Furthermore, although I might be using some packages and commands in my style file, a user might not want to use much of my functionality.  Perhaps he wants to use a different package for managing colour,   Meaning that he might not want the call to `\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` for his document, whilst using my style file.  How can one handle clashes similar to what I described herein?

Comment: As for bold/non-bold for the default style of a package: The user could do another `\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{...}`, if you inform them about this possibility in the package documentation. You could also provide package options for this. You can also "forward" options that are given to your package to other packages your package loads. You should probably look into how you can use options when creating your own package. Also maybe have a look at http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf as well as at other threads on this topic such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34175/47927

Comment: Thank you for the useful links @Jasper