# How to make voltage plus/minus signs bolder

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuitikz

How can I make the voltage plus/minus signs bolder?

The setting `circuitikz/voltage/american font=\boldmath` works, but it is not bold enough. 
It would be nice if there is something which can be placed and applied whenever I create a new components without having to specify coordinate and place them myself.

(Please check the boldness of the voltage plus/minus signs only in the image below.)

[image]

And the plus/minus sign inside the voltage source as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ ultra thick]
\begin{scope}
 circuitikz/voltage/american font=\boldmath
 \draw (7,0) to [
R=R1, v=V1] ++(3,0) node[right]  {boldmath};
\end{scope}
\draw [yshift=-2cm] (7,0) to [
R=R1, v=V1] ++(3,0) node[right]  {default};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The matter would be to find a font with a suitable boldness for you, and then use the keys to change the default chars.

Otherwise, you can build your symbols with basic TeX rules or, if you like, with [picture mode](https://ctan.org/pkg/pict2e?lang=en) (do [not use a `tikzpicture` though](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul)):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\pluuus}{%
    \vrule width 8pt height 5pt depth -3pt\relax
    \kern-5pt\vrule width 2pt height 8pt\kern3pt\relax
}
\newcommand{\miiinus}{%
    \vrule width 8pt height 5pt depth -3pt\relax
}
\ctikzset{voltage/american plus=\pluuus}
\ctikzset{voltage/american minus=\miiinus}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus=\pluuus}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus=\miiinus}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
    circuitikz/inductors/thickness=0.5]

    \draw (0,0) to [cute inductor, v^=$V_L$] ++(3,0);
    \draw (0,0) to [V, l=V, invert] ++(0,3);
    % go back to standard, check alignement
    \ctikzset{voltage/american plus=$+$}
    \ctikzset{voltage/american minus=$-$}
    \draw [thin, red, dashed] (0,0) to[cute inductor, v^=$V_L$] ++(3,0);  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The relevant part in the manual is

[image]

and for the voltage generator symbol

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I see how it works now. I was thinking that you would need to manually do that for every symbol. Anyway, about the plus/minus in the voltage source, first I tried this 
`\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus={\large $\textbf{+}$}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={\large $\textbf{-}$}}`  and it does increase the font size and boldness but not enough I still want it bolder. So I tried a second method as you mentioned.

Comment: I set `\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus={
        \vrule width 8pt height 5pt depth -3pt\kern-5pt\vrule width 2pt height 8pt\relax}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={\kern-5pt\vrule width 8pt height 5pt depth -3pt\relax}}` but the plus/minus isn't aligned inside the voltage source. 
https://ibb.co/YkrLYs9

Comment: Removing `\kern-5pt` seems to work for the minus sign but the plus sign is still not aligned.

Comment: Yes, you have to go back to the end of the sign otherwise LaTeX thinks that the symbol ends at the end of the vertical bar: `\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus={\vrule width 8pt height 5pt depth -3pt\kern-5pt\vrule width 2pt height 8pt\kern3pt\relax}}` (and probably you need the same for the external ones, it's just less visible, I'll fix the answer when I can)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I would be nice if this can be made built-in.

Comment: Done. You can easily add that block to a style file... ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that looks neat! Do you mean that do not put those commands inside `tikzpicture`?

Comment: If you want the same appearance for all the circuits, sticks them in the preamble; you can even create your own little package with the settings: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34175/how-do-i-create-a-latex-package