# How to write my own TexLive package?

Tags: texlive, package-writing

I want to create my own latex package with a `.sty` file in it, and install it via `tlmgr` command.

I've looked it up in Google, and found only this page https://tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html, where I found no detailed procedure to create a new package.

Is there any document about this kind of things?

Comment: For package writing, see [clsguide](https://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide).

Comment: Your package doesn't have to be part of the TexLive distribution, in order to use it locally …

Comment: If you just want to use the package locally, you can store the package file into the local texmf tree such as `/usr/local/texlive/xxxx/texmf-local/tex/latex` and run `sudo mktexlsr` in the terminal. Then you can invoke the package file in your main document directly.

Comment: I know that way, but I do want to build a package that can be installed via `tlmgr`.

Comment: There are very little formal requirements to get a package into TeX Live. Most packages that are uploaded to CTAN (https://ctan.org/) automatically make it into TeX Live (unless their license is not-free or the package is only there to support non-free things). Usually  you "create" a package by bundling its documentation and runtime files together and uploading it to CTAN. There are several questions about that on this site. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34175/35864 has many links that will get you started.